# How to override rules of makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Our current systems have a Makefile for each project that just define variables and include a common (Make.def) with all the rules.

I'm trying to change the common Makefile (Make.def) and add possibility to override some rules:

My idea is to include Makefiles part from most general to concrete ones:

```
-include ./make.rules.rpm
-include ./make.rules.rpm.$(TARGET_ARCH)
-include ./make.rules.rpm.$(TARGET_ARCH).$(PROJECT_NAME)
```

When I use this approach I achieve my goal but with a warning of Makefile:

make.rules.rpm.

```
x86:2: warning: overriding commands for target `rpm'
make.rules.rpm:9: warning: ignoring old commands for target `rpm'
```

As far I have read it's not possible to suppress this warning nor undefine a existing rule.

So I try next aproach:

```
ifeq ($(shell test -e ./make.rules.rpm.$(TARGET_ARCH) && echo -n yes),yes)
    include ./make.rules.rpm.$(TARGET_ARCH)
else
    include ./make.rules.rpm
endif
```

With that I included just one, the more specific. That means that I have to write all rules:

In this example make.rules.rpm have to rules:

```
spec: 
(...)
rpm:
(...)
```

Maybe I just need to overwrite spec rule but keep the same rpm rules as original.

So, here is my question: how I could override a already defined rule on a Makefile using a external Makefile keeping not redefined rules from original?

Comment: You don't need, and shouldn't use, `echo -n`.  Make's `shell` function strips off the trailing newline anyway, and not all versions of `echo` accept the `-n` option: it's not portable.

Comment: The answer to your question is that there's no way to do what you want without modifying the original Makefile.  If you can modify the original makefile then you can do things like put the recipes for the different targets into make variables, and then override them.  Or, depending on what changes you actually need to make to the existing rules, you can define make variables for the non-static parts of the recipe and override those variables.  Etc.

Comment: Oh, just a note: you can greatly simplify (and improve the performance of) your "next approach" using something like this: `include $(firstword $(wildcard ./make.rules.rpm.$(TARGET_ARCH) ./make.rules.rpm))`

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist, I suspected that was not possible to do that! and I will apply your advices!